# Report with large header and footer - alternate blank pages

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, x++, axapta, ax

I have a customised sales confirmation report which contains a lot of customer information in the header, and a lot of T&C text in the footer.

When this report spills over to a second page, all I see printed is a blank page (with the standard header section) then the report continues onto a third page, starting with the customised header. Like so;

```
-----page 1------
header 1
header 2 (large)


lines


footer 1 (large)
footer 2 (page number etc)


-----page 2-----
header 1







footer 2 (page number etc)


-----page 3-----
header 2 (large)


lines


footer 1 (large)
footer 2 (page number etc)
```

After trying lots of different fixes the only additional information I can add is that if I reduce the size of footer 1, the second page prints correctly, but I need those T&Cs on the paperwork. It is also worth noting that I experimented with a `newpage()` call on each line of the body, and despite this meaning there was ample room as I was printing one line per page, I still got the alternate blank page.

One suggestion on another community site is to create the T&C section as a programmable section, but I am not really sure how this would work.

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Do you need the large header/footers on every page?

Comment: Also check the paper size matches the expected one.

Comment: @JanB.Kjeldsen yes i'm afraid so. I am currently only testing by printing to the screen preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was caused by a problem with the DynamicHeight property of a field (or actually a number of fields).

Despite the 3 address fields in "header 2" not being more than 4 lines high, there is a problem with the calculation by AX report generator and this was causing the second header to spill over onto a new page (page 3), even though there was plenty of room for it on page 2.

The fix in this case was to ensure the dynamic height property of any filed in "header 2" was set to no.

Comment: @ian_scho I had to wait 2 days

Answer (score 0):

Check you have no space assigned to Sections that are not disabled, but where the super() is not called in the section Execute.
The blank pages may exist for these. If so explicitly disable the sections

Comment: there is no extra space however header 2 contains a number of addresses which have dynamic height set to Yes, I will try this next.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. AX assigns space for these sections, which is never used because the the execute method never completes. anything that has "public void executeSection(){if(printSection)Super();}" can cause this. You may need to disable the section so Ax doesnt assign the space.